# Object path tracking needs smoothness on a curve

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I have added a constraint to my object to follow the path and the rotation of a front empty that is set to follow the curve; upon the first curve, the empty and the wheels snap back to the front instead of rotating smooth.

GIF here: https://gyazo.com/3b28024cd26c0e471fd9bafec49cd61f

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9cqEXpdL5R2HGKaBd-4dHMgM4VzT1II/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, please share your file, just the important objects (wheel + curve?)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Okay, I will try to delete everything else in the project

Comment: @moonboots I edited the post, you may now download the .blend file.

Comment: I can't see any problem in the file you share but you didn't keep the axle, it may have to do with the axle local axis that is not aligned with the wheel axis?

Comment: I mean, the rotation it does on frames 495-507, it snaps to the path, but I would like to have it smoother, so the rotation wouldn't be so choppy. If you check the GIF, then on 0-2 sec the turn starts and then it literally snaps back straight instead of going smooth like is realistic.